# Random document that doesnt exist in firestore gets selected on android and deleted

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to delete a document from Firestore. I am trying to do this based on the task ID that was randomly generated by Firestone. when a particular task is selected on android, I want to be able to delete that task. However, when I tried debugging the code, it shows a random ID that doesn't exist on the database and tries to delete that, sending me a success message in the console. I am not sure where I am going wrong. Please advice.

```
 public void deleteTasks(View v) {
    userId = mFirebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
    String tskid= fStore.collection("usersData").document(userId).collection("tasks").document().getId();
    DocumentReference taskref = fStore.collection("usersData").document(userId).collection("tasks").document(tskid);
    taskref.delete().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
            Log.d("tag", "Task Deleted Successfully");
        }
    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
            Log.d("tag", "Task Deletion Unsuccessful");
        }
    });
}
```

the above delete method is called on the button using android:OnClick

[The Task I'd like to delete is Circled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VmwvF.png)

Comment: Please edit your question and add your database structure as a screenshot and indicate the exact task you want to remove.

Comment: @AlexMamo, it has been updated, the task I'd like to delete is circled

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are using the following line of code:

```
String tskid= fStore.collection("usersData").document(userId)
    .collection("tasks").document()
    .getId();
```

You are generating a **new** random ID. Actully, you are reserving a key for a document that you'll be writing in the future. When using this line:

```
DocumentReference taskref = fStore.collection("usersData").document(userId)
    .collection("tasks").document(tskid);
```

You are creating a reference to that location. However, when using this line:

```
taskref.delete().addOnCompleteListener(/* ... */);
```

You are trying to delete a document that does not exist and this is because you didn't create it in the first place. If you need to delete a specific document, you need to know the ID. So the following lines of code will do the trick:

```
 public void deleteTasks(View v) {
    userId = mFirebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
    String tskid = "CQ45RKh8Ohd6DXjSQ8RO";
    DocumentReference taskref = fStore.collection("usersData").document(userId)
            .collection("tasks").document(tskid);
    taskref.delete().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
            Log.d("tag", "Task Deleted Successfully");
        }
    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
            Log.d("tag", "Task Deletion Unsuccessful");
        }
    });
}
```

In order to delete that document, I have used the exact same ID that exists in the database.

Comment: the ID here is hardcoded, I want to know if there's a way where on my app, when i select a particular task, (it could be any of the tasks from the list) the ID of that task is taken and then only that task is deleted

Comment: In that case, you should store that ID for each Task object, so it can be used for a future delete operation. Another way would be to create a query that matches your exact document, for example `db.collection("tasks").whereEqualTo("taskName", "YourTaskToDelete")` and then get the id of that document and perform the delete operation as it is explained in my answer. Give it a try and tell me if it works.

Comment: I have already created an object for taskID inside my "TaskList" class. I have setters and getters for it as well. But since I'm very new to android and java, I'm not sure how to call it to delete part

Comment: When you perform a delete operation, you need to have the id of the document that you want to delete. So query the database to get only the document you need to delete, attach a listener, get the id and then simply assign that value to `tskid`, as in my answer.

Comment: I tried code like you mentioned, but i am getting an error. I have added the public void deleteTasks(View v) as an onclick for the deleteButton. But it throws me the error shown in the console. I have updated the code and error its throwing. Please have a look

Comment: I have rolled back to the previous version, as the new question is not related to the initial one. You should make your own attempt given the information in the answer/comments and ask another question if something else comes up.